# Debugger gem not supported in Ruby 2.1.0 / 2.1.1 / 2.1.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, ruby-2.1

I just upgraded my RVM Ruby installation to version 2.1.0 and tried to bundle install when I got the following error:

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
Ruby version 2.1.0 is not supported.
*** extconf.rb failed ***
```

The error of course is self-explanatory, but I was wondering if there was a way to make the Debugger gem work with the latest release of Ruby?

Comment: Which version of the debugger gem are you trying to install? Ruby 2.1.0 is supported only by debugger 1.6.4.

Comment: I am trying to install 1.6.4

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Looks like version 1.6.5 adds support for Ruby 2.1.0. - Works as expected.

Update:
Since Ruby 2.1.1 has been released version 1.6.8 of Debugger should be used.

Comment: yes, switched from 2.1.0 to 2.1.1 and it works ) cool. Many thanks man

Comment: Debugger working as expected in ruby 2 is just luck. It will end up segfaulting or behaving weird. Please use byebug.

Comment: debugger isn't support in ruby 2 https://github.com/cldwalker/debugger/issues/125#issuecomment-43353446

Answer (score 13):

This was mentioned in one of the comments, but I wanted to call attention to it:

**[byebug](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug) is the currently recommended debugger for Ruby 2.0+**

This issue has been documented [here](https://github.com/cldwalker/debugger/issues/125#issuecomment-43353446), and cldwalker, the author of debugger, notes that debugger will be scoped to Ruby 1.9.2 and 1.9.3.

Answer (score 5):

For those using Ruby 2.1.2 and running into this error while building native gem extension:

> No such file or directory @ rb_file_s_stat - ./212/ruby_debug.h (Errno::ENOENT)

The conclusion is to use [byebug](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug) (https://github.com/cldwalker/debugger/issues/131)

Answer (score 0):

The release 1.6.4 is [expected to have limited 2.1.0 support](https://github.com/cldwalker/debugger/issues/109) (which I guess would mean it should at least compile and run). Here's the [commit](https://github.com/cldwalker/debugger/commit/3690a0de63db5bf9f757f6cced41a9270e59d366).

However, other users [reported a compilation issue two days ago (#110)](https://github.com/cldwalker/debugger/issues/110). You may follow the discussion to see when the issue will be fixed. You can also post your compilation error and environment details in the ticket so that the maintainer will have more information available.

Comment: Yes

extconf.rb has if/else construction, which compare ruby versions and if version not 2.0.0 or 1.9.x it say: Ruby version X.X.X is not supported.